# How to run java Hello World program from eclipse IDE using batch file.(without creating an executable jar file)

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jar

is there any way to run my java program from eclipse? I don't want to create an executable jar file of my project.
I have this reference batch file..

```
rem Sets the CLASSPath envirment variable to include all jar files
rem reuired for the JRC then compiles and jars Java  file(s)
rem Make sure you have defined the environment variable JAVA_HOME
rem

set path

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_06

set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%

echo Using JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
echo Using CURRENT_DIR: %CURRENT_DIR%

set _RUNJAVA="%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java"
set _RUNJAVAC="%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javac"
set _RUNJAR="%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jar"




set classpath=D:\BACKUP DATA\Backup\Report Bckup\Reports -Eclipse\WS\src\com\lthed
rem javac %_RUNJAVAC% -classpath "%CLASSPATH%"  test.java
javac  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%"  test.java
%_RUNJAVA% -classpath "%CLASSPATH%"  java test
pause
```

Comment: Read this PDF http://users.drew.edu/bburd/beginprog2/usingeclipse.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you can open .bat file in Eclipse with default editor (double-click), it will run just as from command line

Comment: In this case my condition is, java program must be invoked directly on double clicking batch file. I want to run my batch file on start up

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution

`rem Sets the CLASSPath envirment variable to include all jar files
rem reuired for the JRC then compiles and jars Java  file(s)
rem Make sure you have defined the environment variable JAVA_HOME
rem`

`set path`

`set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java1\jdk1.6.0_24`

`set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%`

`echo Using JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
echo Using CURRENT_DIR: %CURRENT_DIR%
set _RUNJAVA="%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java"
set _RUNJAVAC="%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javac"
set _RUNJAR="%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jar"`

`set classpath=D:\Rush\eclipse\Batch_Run\bin  // path where your Class file is located`

`javac  test_HelloWorld.java
java test_HelloWorld
pause`